# Struggling with implicit resolution when trying to pass a generic class to my csvloader

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm a little baffled as to why this doesn't work...

To learn shapeless I'm implementing everyone's favorite csv loader. It's largely working, I can do things like

```
val caseClasses = CSVConverter[ConcreteImplementationOfACaseClass].from(rowParsedFromFile)
```

However, when I try and change the signature of the method call to

```
def genericWrapper[T <: Product]() = {
     CSVConverter[T].from(rowParsedFromFile)
}
```

and then do something like

```
val test = genericWrapper[ConcreteImplementationOfACaseClass]
```

I am getting an error of "could not find Lazy implicit value of type T"

I'm a bit perplexed... how could this be? I've simply substituted a concrete type for a generic one bounded to be a product. It seems like information is being lost in my implementation.

1. This should be doable right?
2. Any suggestions as to what might be wrong in my implementation?

Or am I way off base here? When I think about it what I’m suggesting is that my implementation can deserialize a string into anything that is a product because it’s fully generic. Shapeless doesn’t know that I’m only going to ask about that one concrete implementation.

If I bound T to be the finite set of case classes I have the ability to convert from string into types for would this work? Or better yet could I somehow bound T such that it’s any case class whose inputs are all strings (or the finite set of conversions I implement) so I don’t have to build such a long list of concrete types?

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you refer to `CSVConverter` like in https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/main/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/csv.scala

You just missed context bound `: CSVConverter`

```
def genericWrapper[T <: Product : CSVConverter]() = {
  CSVConverter[T].from(rowParsedFromFile)
}
```

Instances of type class `CSVConverter` are defined for all case  classes but `T <: Product` doesn't mean that the type `T` is a case class ([There are more types than classes](https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html)) so you need the context bound.